# Reeusing a contract already deployed on remix

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-deployment

I am using with this contract https://pastebin.com/WCGNfbd8 and once I have compiled and deployed it on remix, there is functions that appear under "deployed contract" in "deploy and run transaction" so that I can interract with the contract.
But if I close remix and come back I am not able to find those function again, even if I try to reload the contract, isnt it is supposed to be keep on the blockchain and so I can call it whenever I want ?

Comment: Hi there. Where did you deploy it to? One of the testnets, or Remix's in-built virtual runtime environment (i.e. "Javascript VM")?

Comment: on kovan using injected web3

Comment: Okay, in that case, when you reload Remix, you'll have to use the "Load contract from address" box in the deployment window, and enter the Kovan address you originally deployed it to.

Comment: I dont see a " load from contract" box just "at address" box and when I enter the address of my contract 0xc5c2Af4c6BCdDc32f61c9edc91f07686fbC18b48 I only have a "low level interaction" "call data" box offered not all the original function offered by the contract

Comment: Yes, that box. (Inside the box it says "Load contract from address", but the button label says "At address".) Now you need to select the main contract from the drop-down menu... (There will be libraries and other included contracts listed as well.)

Comment: ah yes, that work, I forget to use "injected web3js " again, thank you

Comment: No problem - glad you got it working :-)